# Can Apache Kafka send non-string messages through a topic?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

A mllib model is trained somewhere and I want it to be sent to somewhere else. When I try to send it through a kafka topic like this

```
val model = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc, "/PATH/To/Model")     
val producer=new Producer[String, LogisticRegressionModel](config)
val data=new KeyedMessage[String, LogisticRegressionModel(topic2,key,model) 
producer.send(data)
producer.close()
```

I would encounter an error like this:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

So, is it possible for kafka to send non-string messages through a topic?

Comment: Yes. But you need to adjust the date type and Serializer. Kafka internally work on byte array anyway and is agnostic to the actual key and value data types. Did you set an appropriate Serializer for you value type in your producer config.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for your fast answer! I didn't realize that before, now the `serializer.class` is `kafka.serializer.StringEncoder`, do I have to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send non-string messages to Kafka topic using Kafka Producer. From 0.9.0 version its better to use Java Client instead of Scala Client.

All you need to do is specifying the correct `Key, Value serializer` in `Properties` like below.

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
 props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Comment: Thank you! I got you, but in this case I need a serializer which can serialize a mllib model, it seems that there is not such a serializer in the library, does it mean that I can't make it?

Comment: @ZefuHu: You can write your custom serializer, if you dont find any serializer available.

Comment: BTW, besides `key.serializer` and `value.serializer` do I have to change this `props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")` ?

Comment: @ZefuHu: please look into this link https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html